# Adding filtered values to an arrary or collection based on different column

Tags: vba

I am just looking to filter down my range into an array or collection so I can use that elseware.

```
Sub TestCollection()

Dim ListedCollection As Collection

Worksheets("Datasources").Activate
ListedColumnID = GetColumnIndexByHeader("ASSET_CLASS")
SecurityColumnID = GetColumnIndexByHeader("TXN_SEC_DESC")

lngLastRowDS = Worksheets("Datasources").Cells(Sheets("DataSources").Rows.Count, SecurityColumnID).End(xlUp).Row


    Set ListedArrary = New Collection

       For Each cell In Range(Worksheets("Datasources").Cells(2, SecurityColumnID), Worksheets("Datasources").Cells(lngLastRowDS, SecurityColumnID))

        If cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "Listed" Then
            ListedCollection.Add cell.Value
            Else
            End If
    Next
    Debug.Print ListedCollection


End Sub
```

I am just having trouble adding to the collection when another column has listed. I cannot manipulate the data source if possible.

Cheers,